# Templated Quicksort

Tags: c++, c++11, template, quick-sort

**Original**

quicksort.h

```
#include <algorithm>

namespace quicksort {

template <typename iterator, typename value_type>
struct traits 
{
    static iterator choose_pivot (iterator first, iterator last) {
        return first + (last - first) / 2 ;
    }

    static iterator partition (iterator first, iterator last, iterator pivot) {
        --last ;
        traits::swap (*pivot, *last) ;
        pivot = last ;

        while (true) {
            while (*first < *pivot) {
                ++first ;
            }

            --last ;

            while (*pivot < *last) {
                --last ;
            }

            if (first >= last) {
                traits::swap (*pivot, *first) ;
                return first ;
            }

            traits::swap (*first, *last) ;
            ++first ;
        }
    }

    static void swap (value_type &lhs, value_type &rhs) {
        std::swap (lhs, rhs) ;
    }
};


template <typename iterator, typename value_type>
void sort (iterator first, iterator last)
{
    if (first >= last) {
        return ;
    }

    auto pivot = traits<iterator, value_type>::choose_pivot (first, last) ;
    auto next_pivot = traits<iterator, value_type>::partition (first, last, pivot) ;
    sort <iterator, value_type> (first, next_pivot) ;
    sort <iterator, value_type> (next_pivot + 1, last) ;
}

} // end of namespace quicksort
```

Driver.cpp

```
#include "quicksort.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename DataType, template <typename ...> class Container>
void print_container (const Container <DataType> &container)
{
    for (const DataType &d : container) {
        std::cout << d << " " ;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl ;
}

template <typename DataType, template <typename ...> class Container>
void run_test (const std::string &name, Container <DataType> &&container)
{
    std::cout << name << ":\n" ;
    print_container <DataType, Container> (container) ;
    quicksort::sort <typename Container<DataType>::iterator, DataType> (std::begin (container), std::end (container)) ;
    std::cout << name << " quicksorted:\n" ;
    print_container <DataType, Container> (container) ;
}

int main (void)
{
    run_test <int, std::vector> ("vec1", std::vector <int> {5, 4, 3, 1, 2}) ;
    run_test <int, std::vector> ("vec2", std::vector <int> {5, 4, 10, 7, 6, 11, 14, 17, 12, 3, 1, 2}) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

**Updated**

quicksort.h

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

namespace quicksort {
namespace detail {

struct first_pivot_selector
{
    template <typename Iterator>
    static Iterator choose_pivot (Iterator first, Iterator last) {
        return first ;
    }
};

struct middle_pivot_selector
{
    template <typename Iterator>
    static Iterator choose_pivot (Iterator first, Iterator last) {
        auto distance = std::distance (first, last) / 2 ;
        std::advance (first, distance) ;
        return first ;
    }
};

struct last_pivot_selector
{
    template <typename Iterator>
    static Iterator choose_pivot (Iterator first, Iterator last) {
        return last ;
    }
};

// Kept for debugging
struct my_pivot_selector
{
    template <typename Iterator>
    static Iterator choose_pivot (Iterator first, Iterator last) {
        return first + (last - first) / 2 ;
    }
};

struct std_partition {
    template <typename Iterator>
    static Iterator partition (Iterator first, Iterator last, Iterator pivot)
    {
        using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type ;
        return std::stable_partition (first, last, [=] (const value_type &v) {
            return v < *pivot ;
        }) ;
    }
};

// Kept for debugging
struct my_partition
{
    template <typename Iterator>
    static Iterator partition (Iterator first, Iterator last, Iterator pivot)
    {
        --last ;
        std::swap (*pivot, *last) ;
        pivot = last ;

        while (true) {
            while (*first < *pivot) {
                ++first ;
            }

            --last ;

            while (*pivot < *last) {
                --last ;
            }

            if (first >= last) {
                std::swap (*pivot, *first) ;
                return first ;
            }

            std::swap (*first, *last) ;
            ++first ;
        }
    }
};

} // end of namespace detail

template <typename Iterator, typename Pivot = detail::middle_pivot_selector, typename Partition = detail::my_partition>
void sort (Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    if (first >= last) {
        return ;
    }

    auto pivot = Pivot::choose_pivot (first, last) ;
    auto next_pivot = Partition::partition (first, last, pivot) ; 
    sort <Iterator, Pivot, Partition> (first, next_pivot) ;
    sort <Iterator, Pivot, Partition> (next_pivot + 1, last) ;
}

} // end of namespace quicksort
```

Driver.cpp

```
#include "quicksort.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Container>
void print_container (const Container &container)
{
    for (const typename Container::value_type &v : container) {
        std::cout << v << " " ;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl ;
}

template <typename Container>
void run_test (const std::string &name, Container container)
{
    std::cout << name << ":\n" ;
    print_container (container) ;
    quicksort::sort (std::begin (container), std::end (container)) ;
    std::cout << name << " quicksorted:\n" ;
    print_container (container) ;
}

int main (void)
{
    run_test ("vec1", std::vector <int> {5, 4, 3, 1, 2}) ;
    run_test ("vec2", std::vector <int> {5, 4, 10, 7, 6, 11, 14, 17, 12, 3, 1, 2}) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

**Problem**
Based on these changes, `std_partition::partition` produces incorrect results.  I found some code that follows a similar strategy on [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Quicksort#C.2B.2B).

```
T middle = partition (begin, end, bind2nd(
                    less<typename iterator_traits<T>::value_type>(), *begin));
sort (begin, middle);
T new_middle = begin;
sort (++new_middle, end);
```

The problem is that this would break my current algorithm. I guess I could do a partial-specialization.

Comment: I'm sorry that I asking this. But you trying to implement quicksort algoritm, or it is somehow different from std::sort? There is no offense, I just not really good understand quicksort algoritm, and can't figure out,  is it better than std's one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with things that can be cleaned up in your `traits` struct:

Firstly, by convention, all template parameters should be `UpperCaseFirstLetter`. Secondly, you don't need to pass in a `value_type`, because you can get this directly from the iterator using `std::iterator_traits`. Finally, using a `struct` with all static functions smells a bit: this should simply be an inner namespace. Usually, when it's details that you don't want to expose to people, the chosen name for the namespace would be `detail`. Let's apply that to the `choose_pivot` function:

```
#include <iterator>

namespace quicksort
{
namespace detail
{

template <typename Iterator>
Iterator choose_pivot(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    auto distance = std::distance(first, last) / 2;
    std::advance(first, distance);
    return first;
}

} // end namespace detail

...
```

It's now using `std::distance` and `std::advance`. This will work with any iterator type, but performance will obviously be degraded. If you want to enforce that the iterator is random access, you can always throw in a `static_assert`:

```
 static_assert(std::is_same<std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category,
                            std::random_access_iterator_tag>::value,
               "Iterator must be random access");
```

The `partition` function you've got currently could be very easily replaced with `std::partition`:

```
template <typename Iterator>
Iterator partition(Iterator first, Iterator last, Iterator pivot)
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
    return std::partition(first, last, [=](const value_type& v) { return v < *pivot; });
}
```

If you want to make it really customisable, then I'd suggest doing that as template parameters on the `sort` function. Also, it's always a good idea to provide defaults, because otherwise your users are going to have to specify masses of template parameters, which is annoying. This will require modifying the `choose_pivot` function above into a `struct\class`:

```
namespace detail
{
struct pivot
{
    template <typename Iterator>
    Iterator choose_pivot(Iterator first, Iterator last)
    {
        auto distance = std::distance(first, last) / 2;
        std::advance(first, distance);
        return first;
    }
};
} // end namespace detail
```

Then your sort function would look something like:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Pivot = detail::pivot>
void sort(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    if (first >= last) {
        return;
    }

    auto pivot = Pivot().choose_pivot(first, last);
    auto next_pivot = detail::partition(first, last, pivot);
    sort<Iterator, Pivot>(first, next_pivot);
    sort<Iterator, Pivot>(next_pivot + 1, last);
}
```

A similar pattern can be used for anything else you want to specify.

Note that we've gotten rid of having to specify template parameters (almost) everywhere. In fact, the same can be done in your `run_test` function:

```
...
quicksort::sort(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
...
```

The compiler is smart enough to deduce parameters, so let it do the hard work.

Comment: Is naming the pivot struct `pivot` a good idea if I want to have multiple pivot choosing algorithms? Would it be better to call that struct something like `middle_pivot_selector`?

Comment: @red_eight Sure, `middle_pivot_selector` would probably be a better name for it.

Comment: I have updated my code base on your and @MichaelUrman 's suggestions. The `std::partition` algorithm does not work correctly for some reason. I'm using `std::stable_partition` instead, but I'm getting the same incorrect results. When I use my partition method, everything still works fine.

Comment: @red_eight My apologies with that. When I tested that what I'd written was working, I forgot to specify template parameters for `sort` (even though I included them above), and it must have switched to using `std::sort`.

Comment: @Yuushi: I don't think your `partition` function works, because `pivot` points into the range [`first`, `last`) and therefore the value of `*pivot` will change as the elements are swapped around inside `std::partition`, which means the lambda you've given to `std::partition` is not a predicate (it can give two different results for the same inputs).

Answer (score 5):

Regarding Driver.cpp's rvalue reference in `void run_test (const std::string &name, Container <DataType> &&container)`, since `Container` is being deduced, this isn't necessarily an rvalue reference; this could be either an rvalue or lvalue reference. Scott Meyers calls this construct a [universal reference](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) and offers advice on how to use them, as well as their pitfalls.

Typically the only place you need to care rvalue references are for implementing move constructors and forwarding functions (the "universal reference" is great for forwarding functions). Outside of those, the rules haven't changed much: take a reference if you want to change things, take a const reference if you don't want to change things, and take it by value if you need to change things internally. The last of these is automatically move-constructed if the type supports it.

And no, while your construct currently looks like one for a forwarding function, your function doesn't really forward anything. So you probably shouldn't be using std::forward (the conditional move) or even std::move (the unconditional rvalue cast) in `run_test`. This is because the only time you can afford for `run_test` to move the container is the last line where it calls `print_container` and  `print_container` only accepts a const reference. Given that, I would probably remove the references entirely - semantically `run_test` accepts a container and then modifies it internally - it should just accept raw `Container<DataType>`, and not care whether it was moved or copied to get there.

Comment: +1 For the article. That was a great read, but a tad complicated. Man, passing non-trivial objects by value is going to take time to get used to.